# Missing images in html file when i loaded the html file via android webview

Tags: android, base64, android-webview, image

I am downloading an HTML form from a webserver and displaying the form on android webview. There are few images in HTML file (images src is encoded in Base64). But images are not showing up.

Where is the problem?

```
myBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL("", downloadedFormContent , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I have saved the form content into a local html file (/sdcard/test.html) and loaded the html file. but still images are not showing up.

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/test.html");
```

I'm able to see all the images if I open the same HTML file using web-browser(IE, Chrome).

Where am I going wrong?

```
Here is the src of html file :

<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      //css goes here
 </style>
</head>
<body> 

<img src="data:image;base64,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" width="200px" height="90"  alt="installer_signature" />
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you open this file with images in android device's default web browser?

Comment: i have opened the file in android device's default web browser but still images are missing.

Comment: share the HTMl file content that you are trying to use

Comment: Look `test.html` file code and see where it refers to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace

```
data:image;base64,
```

with

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

you were missing the `content-type` of image in `src`

Comment: happy that it helped you. please don't forget to come back and accept the answer, after the SO lock-in period. :)